# Obtener datos de una foto tomada con Android, Deseo la hora exacta de tomada

Tags: android

tengo una aplicación que toma una foto con un intent y debo obtener el momento (hora) exacta cuando se capturo, el problema es que al hacer la foto con `intent`, tomo la hora al darle ok (`onActivityResult()` ) a la foto capturada, y si el usuario toma la foto y tarda un minuto en presionar ok, me guarda la hora del ok y no del momento que tomo la foto, soy algo nuevo en android.

```
 //Comprobamos que la foto se a realizado
            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Creamos un bitmap con la imagen recientemente
                //almacenada en la memoria
                        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                                "/System32photo/" + file);
                SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS");
                Date myDate = new Date();
                String date = timeStampFormat.format(myDate);
                fechatomada =date.substring(0,8);
                horatomada = date.substring(8,14);
```

pienso que la foto en sus propiedades tiene el dato que necesito pero no se como tomarlo cuando este la imagen cargada en un `ImagenView`

Comment: Guardar la fecha cuando tomas la foto es complicado ya que el intent simplemente abre la camara pero es independiente a el momento en que tomas la foto, el momento que puedes determinar para salvar la foto es cuando la guardas, antes de regresar a onActivityResult!.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, con un tutorial que encontre me costo porque lo habia intentado y nada que me funcionaba. leo las propiedades con (exif) de la foto luego de capturada. aqui esta la solcuion por si a alguien le sirve http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/10/read-exif-of-jpg-file-using.html gracias por el interes Jorgesys

Comment: ohhh es verdad hace tiempo lo use para videos para extraer los datos que previamente se inyectaron al video https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html =| sería bueno agregaras tu solución tal vez haciendo referencia al código que encontraste!, sería buena ayuda para otros.

Comment: Edite tu respuesta, cuando puedas marcala como resuelta, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es mi solución, mediante el uso de la clase [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) para poder leer los atributos de la foto que capture.

```
package com.AndroidExif;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidExifActivity extends Activity {

 String imagefile ="/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/myphoto.jpg";
 ImageView image;
 TextView Exif;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        Exif = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exif);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefile);
        image.setImageBitmap(bm);

        Exif.setText(ReadExif(imagefile));
    }

    String ReadExif(String file){
     String exif="Exif: " + file;
     try {
   ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(file);

   exif += "\nIMAGE_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH);
   exif += "\nIMAGE_WIDTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH);
   exif += "\n DATETIME: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
   exif += "\n TAG_MAKE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);
   exif += "\n TAG_MODEL: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL);
   exif += "\n TAG_ORIENTATION: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
   exif += "\n TAG_WHITE_BALANCE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE);
   exif += "\n TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH);
   exif += "\n TAG_FLASH: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH);
   exif += "\nGPS related:";
   exif += "\n TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
   exif += "\n TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP);
   exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
   exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
   exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
   exif += "\n TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
   exif += "\n TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD: " + exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD);

   Toast.makeText(AndroidExifActivity.this, 
     "finished", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(AndroidExifActivity.this, 
     e.toString(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

     return exif;
    }

}
```

---

Obtuve el código de este articulo:

[**Leer Exif de un archiv JPG usando ExifInterface.**](http://android-coding.blogspot.mx/2011/10/read-exif-of-jpg-file-using.html)